# How can I debug Flutter apps on Chrome and have Android Studio stop at breakpoints?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, flutter-web

If I press `Ctrl+Enter`, `Shift+F9` or `Shift+F10`, or go to `Run > Run 'main.dart'` or `Run > Debug 'main.dart'`, Android Studio tries to run or debug my app on my android device, if connected, or else reports 'No connected devices...'. Debug behaves as expected, stopping at breakpoints.

('No connected devices' is already strange, as `flutter devices` returns that both android and Chrome devices are connected and `flutter doctor` returns no issues. Flutter web is enabled.)

If I go to terminal in Android Studio, I can execute `flutter run -d chrome`, and the app runs in 'debug mode' on Chrome. **This debug mode, however, does not stop at breakpoints or behave in any obviously different way to if the app were simply run.**

How can I run flutter apps on Chrome and have Android Studio stop at breakpoints?

Comment: my `AS 4.1` and dart plugin `201.9317` works just fine - what version do you use?

Comment: AS 4.1.2. My dart plugin is now 201.9317 after updating (forget what it was before) and still not seeming to hit breakpoints.

I'm wondering if there's something I'm missing in the process of debugging via terminal. Is there anything I should do besides running `flutter run --debug -d chrome` and having breakpoints in the code (set via GUI)?

Comment: tried `Shift+F9` (Run > Debug 'main.dart')?

Comment: Yes. This returns 'No connected devices found [...]' unless my android device is connected. I've also now enabled linux desktop as a device, and it behaves the same as chrome with respect to debugging.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that Android Studio is able to see the Chrome to run the project as a web app, you can select the Chrome from the list of devices dropdown - highlighted in a rectangle in the picture. You can also run the app in debug mode by clicking on the shortcut button from the toolbar - highlighted in circle.

[image: List of devices, debug]

I'm currently running Flutter plugin version 71.2.3 and the breakpoints works as expected. Dart plugin is on version 213.7433